# Specify content root for new base window in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there a way to specify the "hole" for additional XAML content in WPF?

For instance if I create `MySuperWindowBase` and have some XAML in it with a layout, how can I specify where to place additional content in the layout in a subclass of `MySuperWindowBase`?

For a simplified example

MySuperWindowBase:

```
<Window>
   <StackPanel>
     <!-- Force child content here -->
   </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MyChildWindow:

```
<MySuperWindowBase>
    <TextBlock>Place me in the StackPanel</TextBlock>
</MySuperWindowBase>
```

Comment: Sounds like `ContentPresenter`. Your description is too vague to tell you anything beyond that.

Comment: @EdPlunkett i updated.

Comment: Is this Xamarin or WPF? StackLayout doesn't exist in WPF. I can give you a WPF answer,, which may need some modification if you're using it in Xamarin.

Comment: @EdPlunkett got my wires crossed - this is WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to give the base class window a template. Gusdor's answer explains everything but how to write a template that'll display the control's `Content` property, so here's an illustrative example of a control template for a window. The window's content is whatever's inside the `<Window></Window>` element in your ChildWindow.xaml file: `<TextBlock>Place me in the StackPanel</TextBlock>` is the placeholder content in your question. By default, that XAML visual tree fragment will get assigned to the window's `Content` property.

The `ContentPresenter` control presents the content. By default, it looks at the templated parent's `Content` property, but you can change that by setting the ContentPresenter's ContentSource property to the name of a different property of the templated parent.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Window" x:Key="WindowBaseTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Border 
            BorderBrush="Gray"
            BorderThickness="1"
            Margin="10"
            Padding="20"
            Background="GhostWhite"
            >
            <ContentPresenter
                />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

`ContentPresenter` looks like there must be magic, but it's just the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new `Style` for the window -
   https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WPF-styling-a-Window-in-fcf4e4ce
2. Set the `ContentTemplate` property to include your mandatory elements.

Almost every other method will cause you to run into namescope issues at some point.